# (PPT VBA) Select textrange.characters failure

Tags: vba, select, powerpoint

I want to select some characters in textrange. It works when I use "With activepresentation.slides(2).shapes(2)".
The codes:

```
dim Txtrng as textrange
dim Words_Instr as integer
dim aa as string
With ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(2)
    Set Txtrng = .TextFrame.textRange
    aa = "AAAA"
    Words_Instr = InStr(Txtrng, aa)
    If Words_Instr > 0 Then
        Txtrng.Characters(Words_Instr, Len(aa)).Select
    end if
end with
```

It doesn't work when I use "pres.". I want to do the same thing in every shape of every slide.
The Codes:

```
dim pres as presentation
dim sli as slide
dim shp as shape
dim Txtrng as textRange
dim Words_Instr as integer
dim aa as string
set pres=Presentations.Open(filename:=f1)
aa = "AAAA"
For Each sLi In pRes.Slides
    for each sHp in sLi.shapes
        If sHp.HasTextFrame = msoTrue Then
            Set Txtrng = sHp.TextFrame.textRange
            Words_Instr = InStr(Txtrng, aa)
            If Words_Instr > 0 Then
                Txtrng.Characters(Words_Instr, Len(aa)).Select
            end if
        end if  
    next                        
next
```

It always showed error in “txtrng.characters(...).select”

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: So weird, I test it but select the text successfully

Comment: I am a new visitor in StackOverflow. I'm not familiar with it. Thank you, Kin Siang. Since you can run it successfully, I will try to find other possible ways.

Comment: No, i am using exact same code from you without modification, but select it successfully...

Answer (score 0):

If you only refer to current presentation instead of open another `ppt`, then the following code will do, I only change `set pre` part only, copy and paste this code into your existing `ppt` and run it, it will select the `text` on the shape:

```
Sub test()

Dim pres As Presentation
Dim sli As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim Txtrng As TextRange
Dim Words_Instr As Integer
Dim aa As String
Set pres = ActivePresentation
aa = "AAAA"
For Each sli In pres.Slides
    For Each shp In sli.Shapes
        If shp.HasTextFrame = msoTrue Then
            Set Txtrng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
            Words_Instr = InStr(Txtrng, aa)
            If Words_Instr > 0 Then
                Txtrng.Characters(Words_Instr, Len(aa)).Select
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: I need to open all the files in the folder. The codes:    
    For Each f1 In fc
        If f1 Like "*.pptx" Then
              Set pres = Presentations.Open(filename:=f1)

I'm sure the codes are right, because I always use them in other subs.

Comment: Maybe you try open specific file and test because i try open file with no issue. Or one of ppt is `protected`?

Comment: I just found some shapes work, and some shapes doesn't in the same file.  So I guess the problem is about the shape's property. I will keep trying.   Do you know how to close the question since I have known the keypoint?

Comment: I see, it is glad you found the rootcause. To close the question, you may delete it or accept my answer :)

Comment: @Rachel1208  Add another if/then test after  If sHp.HasTextFrame = msoTrue Then ... If sHp.TextFrame.HasText = True Then

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg  I follow your suggestion, but it still can't work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Rachel1208 Ah, I see the problem. You can only select text on the slide currently in view. But I'm puzzled:  what good is just selecting the text on every slide, even if you *could* do it?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg I need those characters' positions. If I can select successfully, I can use the code like " hh = ActiveWindow.Selection.textRange.BoundTop" to get the data.

Now I can select successfully. Here are my codes.
    
    
    "For Each sli In pres.Slides
    k = sli.SlideIndex
    ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide k"

Comment: You rarely *need* to select anything when you're automating PPT, and you generally shouldn't (slows down your code, makes it more fragile).  Txtrng.Characters(Words_Instr, Len(aa)).BoundTop should do it.

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg You are right. I didn't know that before you told me. Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: @Rachel1208 Happy to have been able to help. A good friend taught me the same lesson years ago; I'm just paying him back by paying it forward.